# What game is being played in the movie Hatari?

Tags: props, hatari

Dallas and Luis are playing a game. It appears to be a four-tier play field, each tier having approximately 8x8 (64) squares. They're playing with colored discs.

**What is this game?**

[image]

Comment: Cheers, @steelersquirrel. I thought about creating a [tag:hatari] tag, but decided against it as the odds of a second question about the movie are pretty low.

Comment: No worries.  I'm kinda a tag freak :P  Great question for my favorite John Wayne movie!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This appears to be ***[Checkline](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/123473/crestline-english-red-box-edition)***, a variant of 3-dimensional noughts & crosses.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Click to enbiggen the rules